# How to retrieve profile picture of linkedin user android

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I have tried to fetch the profile picture of linkedin user by the following url

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/"+userID+"/picture-url

But i'm getting file not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hopefully it should work for you or at least give you an idea how to go about it.
//picUrl is your linkedin contact image url

```
BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(picUrl,mContactPic);
task.execute();

/* Async task to download the image from URL and display it in imageView*/
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

    /*contact bitmap url */
    private final String mUrl;

    /*contact image view*/
    ImageView mView;
    public BitmapWorkerTask(String aUrl, ImageView aView) {
        mUrl = aUrl;
        mView = aView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

        if(mBgTaskCancel) {
            /*cancel the execution of this task if the mBgTaskCancel flag is true  */
            this.cancel(false);
        } else {
            /*else get the contact bitmap from the url  */
            final Bitmap bitmap = Utils.getBitmapFromURL(this.mUrl);
            return bitmap;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap aBitmap) {
        if (aBitmap != null) {
            /*set the image bitmap if it is not null */
            mView.setImageBitmap(aBitmap);
        }
    }
}


/**
* function to download the image from url
*/

 public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String aURL) {
    URL lBitmapURL;
    Bitmap lBitmap = null;
    try {
        lBitmapURL = new URL(aURL);
        InputStream lInStream = lBitmapURL.openStream();
        lBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(lInStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return lBitmap;
}
```